# Can someone teach me how to understand this code, and point out my mistake?

Tags: javascript

[image]

Hello im a newbie in learning javascript. May I know how the code works line by line? My answer is 12121212 but modal answer is 111222333444.

To my understanding, the inner loop must run finish first. The outer loop will be the number of times the loop will run. So, when i = 1 (first loop), j = 1, then since it ++, it will become 2 but not 3 since its j<3.

After that loop number 2, will print out j = 1 and 2 again
This continues until the 4th loop ends.

Comment: `i` is printed, not `j`. Also, `j` starts at zero, not one.

Comment: No, the first iteration of the outer loop is first run, then the inner loop is executed and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept behind your code is nested looping. So you need to multiply the count of each loops to get the total number of loops happening in the code. In your case

for(i=1;i<5;i++) runs 4 times i=1,2,3,4
for(j=0;i<3;j++) runs 3 times j=0,1,2

Here, It is 3*4 = 12 times

When it enters the first loop(i.e., i). The loop inside it runs 3 times. Since you are printing i, For the first loop, It would be 111. And then for the second loop. It would be 222 and So on.

You would understand better If you write like below,

```
for(i=1;i<5;i++){
    for(j=0;j<3;j++){
        document.write(i);
    } 
  document.write('\n')
}
```

And the output would be,

```
1
1
1


2
2
2


3
3
3


4
4
4
```

Answer (score 0):

You are writing the i, not j. So at first, you write i = 1. Then loop to j = 1, which is still < 3, so write i = 1 again. Then j = 2, still below 3, so write 1 again. When j = 3, its back to outer loop, now i = 2, and so on.

Comment: Thank you! I was so confused in the order of the pattern:>

Answer (score 0):

For a single value of outer loop, the inner loop will complete all the 3 iterations. There are only 3 values of i: 1, 2, and 3. [See this figure.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWRzN.png)

Comment: `i` will also be `4` since `4 < 5`